# ClassCastException problems

Tags: java, arraylist, certificate, classcastexception

I was programming a Cert Parser with eclipse,
I use my country government departments provide class that it can parser a specialized certificate in my country.
But I have little trouble about something,
When I compiler my code,the console show these information：

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to tw.com.chttl.hipki.CredentialBean
at CertParser.Read_Normal(CertParser.java:41)
at CertParser.<init>(CertParser.java:26)
at CertParser.main(CertParser.java:155)
```

About ClassCastException problems, I know is a enforce transform problems.
But I use class is String type, like：

`public String getNonce(){`
`return _credential.getNonce();`
`}`

or

`public String getSubjectDN(){`
`returnCertParser.getSubjectDN(_credential.getSignerCertificate(0));}`

And possible error in my code：

```
private int Read_Normal(JPanel panel){
    String Field;
    try{
        FileInputStream file_inputstream=new FileInputStream(CA_Name);
        CertificateFactory cf=CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        CredentialBean bean=(CredentialBean)cf.generateCertificates(file_inputstream);
        Field=bean.getSubjectDN();
        CA_ItemData[0][0]="getSubjectDN";
        CA_ItemData[0][1]=Field;
        System.out.println("getSubjectDN："+Field);
        Field=bean.getIssuerDN();
        CA_ItemData[1][0]="getIssuerDN";
        CA_ItemData[1][1]=Field;
        System.out.println("getIssuerDN："+Field);
        file_inputstream.close();
        final JTable table = new JTable(CA_ItemData, columnNames);
        TableColumn tc=null;
        tc = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        tc.setPreferredWidth(600); 
        panel.add(table);
    }catch(Exception exception){    
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This class all String type, and my code is String too.
What is this  problems mean?

My English is not principal in my country,if I have any mistake, please forgive me.

Thank you.

Comment: what does `cf.generateCertificates` do? Because you are expecting a `CredentialBean`, but you are getting an `arrayList`. Probably CredentialBean bean = ((CredentialBean)((java.util.ArrayList)cf.generateCertificates(file_inputstream))[0]);

Comment: Thank your answer.
But it show `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList` error.

If want to get String type, where is mistake in my code ?

Comment: in java an array `[]` is not the same thing as an `ArrayList`. Fixing my previous comment `CredentialBean bean = ((CredentialBean)((java.util.ArrayList)cf.generateCertificates(file_inputstream)‌​).get(0));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `cf.generateCertificates`, which returns a collection of certificates (in this case a list).

If you are creating just a single certificate, you should call `cf.generateCertificate`, in which case you would be able to successfully cast the returned value.

Alternatively, if you really do want to create multiple certificates, then you will need to iterate over the elements of the returned collection, casting (and processing) each one in turn.

Comment: When I use `cf.generateCertificate` ,change to `CredentialBean bean=(CredentialBean)cf.generateCertificate(file_inputstream);`.

It show error with `Cannot cast from Certificate to CredentialBean`.

But if I use `Certificate` ,it can useful `Certificate ban=cf.generateCertificate(file_inputstream) with no error;`.

Comment: @user2452153 Based on your comment I think you may have misunderstood what casting is.  It does **not** convert between types.  It is simply a way to tell the compiler's type system that you know an object is of a more specific type than the types guarantee.  If you're wrong - if you cast something to `Certificate` when it *isn't* a `Certificate`, you'll get the ClassCastException at runtime.  Consider this [Upcasting vs Downcasting tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50451-upcasting-downcasting/) if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

The method `generateCertificates` returns an arraylist (of certificates, perhaps?), and you try to squeeze the array into a `CredentialBean` variable.

Comment: That mean array to String?
That will be a big mistake for I done.

Comment: No. I mean what I have written. In your code, you take an ArrayList object. Then you cast it to CredentialBean. Which is impossible and forbidden. It is not a CredentialBean, so you can't magically cast it into one.